# ASP.NET MVC 3 with already built SQL Server on different databases

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC3 project in C# that is using an already existing SQL Server database.

The SQL Server has different databases, one for each customer. Each customer database has numerous tables, but I'm interested in only one table.

So, I'm interested in retrieving (and not updating or deleting) data from the same table of every customer.
This is the database configuration example:
DatabaseCustomerName1
 - TableNeeded
DatabaseCustomerName2
 - TableNeeded
DatabaseCustomerNameN
 - Tableneeded

The question is... how do I create the model?

Knowing that If I had to do it for just one customer I would create the model basing on the fields of the tables, how can I manage the situation of having multiple customers?

Thanks in advance.

Attila

Answer (score 1):

You should have an interface for Repository class
for example and different implementations for each custumer data base

```
    internal interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
}

class ProductRepositoryCustumerOne : IProductRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        //code to retrieve data
    }
}

class ProductRepositoryCustumerTwo : IProductRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        //code to retrieve data
    }
}
```

after you can inject with IoC container what implementation you need

Comment: I see it's a very clean solution, but I need to manage the situation dynamically, they can create a new customer and I should handle it without creating everytime a new class for it. Is there a way with this solution?

Comment: If you will use IoC container the objects of Repository class will be created as singletons, that mean one time

Answer (score 0):

Let me just clarify your question, are you saying you've got 
a number of customers with a database each?

So...

Databases

- Customer A
- Customer B

And for each of those customers you're saying you have a table that you want to access so you have

- Customer A > TheTable
- Customer B > TheTable

So you're asking, how can you create a Model that will work for any customer to access TheTable?

Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. So far I created the model "to model" the common table. How do I print, for example, the value of the same table of all the Customers in a "Summary" page? Ordering it by customer, (i.e. keeping track of the DB name)

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a Sql View over all tables based on a select link this:

```
 Select 'Customer 1' as Customer, c.* from FirstDb.dbo.Cusotmers c
 Union Select 'Customer 2' as Customer, c.* from SecondDb.dbo.Cusotmers c
 Union ...
```

Than you can handel this view with e.g. EF or linq to sql.

Comment: Interesting solution, i'll ask the database admin if it is possible to create that kind of view.
But how can I keep track of the customer source in the view? In this way I only have a view with all the datas of all the customers, how can I have a view ordered by customer?

Comment: Well, in this example you have a column called "Customer". If you are using Linq you simply can order as you want:
'Customers.OrderBy( c => c.Customer )...'

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume you are using Entity Framework? Is the schema in all the databases the same?

You should be able to create your model against one of the databases. Then whenever you want to select a different customer you will need to change the Initial Catalog (or equivalent) value in the connection string before you create your data context.

I don't have any code handy at the moment.  Does this help?

Comment: I'm using Linq to Sql, sorry i forgot to mention it.
The schema in all the database is the same. The problem is that I have to display in a page the data of all the customers, not one by one